# How to display data queried through Flask on HTML while the query is still running

Tags: javascript, html, flask

So, I am making a SQL query and processing the data acquired by SQL to a JSON format(so in a program that generates JSON). But the process takes a very long time I am talking about upwards of 6 minutes, so I am trying to display the data shown as the processing of the data is being done, but I am quite unsure as to how to go about that.

The only idea I have had is to split the queries into 10 at a time and display the 10 and run the rest in the background and if load them as required(but again no clue how to go about that)

I am familiar with FLASK,HTML,JS,Jquery(barely). I am open to new frameworks, but if possible I would like to stick with what I know. Any solution is appreciated.

Comment: there are multiple solutions, you can use websockets for returning query state to the client, or send requests to the server separately (one by one) and after each one display the progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into Celery.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/celery/

Basically, you would offload your sql queries to a celery task. The task could run each query sequentially and keep saving the results to a database, a redis cache, or a plain file.

Then your html/js would set a timer/interval to do a fetch() every few seconds to a flask route that reads from that database until it is done.

Comment: Its not the SQL queries that take long, actually that finishes up super quick, but the dataframe that I convert the query into and use the .apply function is really slow.

Comment: It's ok, the task is not limited to sql queries. You can run anything in there.